# How can I take a regular expression from the beginning of one line and copy it to the beginning of following lines?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, posix

I'm writing a script that converts text from pdf documents and formats it in CSV to be used later on. I've come to an issue where I need to append additional information onto certain lines to complete the data and don't know how to achieve it with `sed`. The document looks like so:

```
# "date","description","cost","total"
"31 01 19","Purchase from SHOP","1.23","1.23"
"Direct debit to COMPANY","2.34","3.57"
"Purchase from SHOP","3.45","7.02"
"01 02 19","Received from PERSON","1.23","5.79"
"Purchase to SHOP","4.56","10.35"
```

When it should look like this:

```
# "date","description","cost","total"
"31 01 19","Purchase from SHOP","1.23","1.23"
"31 01 19","Direct debit to COMPANY","2.34","3.57"
"31 01 19","Purchase from SHOP","3.45","7.02"
"01 02 19","Received from PERSON","1.23","5.79"
"01 02 19","Purchase to SHOP","4.56","10.35"
```

How could I achieve this with `sed`?

I have tried:

```
/^(\"[[:digit:]]{2} [[:digit:]]{2} [[:digit:]]{2}\",)/{
    h
    N
    /^(\"[^\"]*\",\"(0|[1-9][[:digit:]]{,2}(,[[:digit:]]{1,3})*)\.[[:digit:]]{2})\",?{2})/{
        G
        s/((.*))\n((.*))/\2,\1/
    }
}
```

But that does not seem to do anything, even with the regular expressions tested to ensure they match what I'm after.
Am I doing something wrong here or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: With awk? `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{if(NF==4) {save=$1} else {$0=save FS $0}}1' file`

Comment: I am astounded to learn that there is something harder to parse than sed, namely pseudo-sed. Please give us either some real data, or simple phony data that we're allowed to take literally.

Comment: @Cyrus I have edited the comment with new formatting and tried your awk script, yet all it did was add `,"` to the lines that already had the date and did nothing to those that didn't unfortunately.

Comment: @Beta I have updated the comment to include my current implementations of the code and a more informative example.

Comment: Looking at your regex I can't help but feel you are using the wrong tool for the job. Maybe you should switch to Perl or Python.

Comment: @jww What about the regex suggests that? I don't understand what it is about designing this as a shell script that makes it less appropriate than using Perl/Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'N;/\n".. .. .."/!s/^([^,]+,).*\n/&\1/;P;D' file
```

Append the following line and it does not start with a date, insert the previous lines date, print/delete the previous line and repeat.